# Implement the functionalities for Counter class such that the class Interface and Implementation are separate? what is meant by that in C++

Tags: c++

Define a class Counter having the attribute count (type int). For the class
Counter, implement the following functionalities: (Q8-Q11)

Q8. Constructors which allow statements like:

```
Counter c1;//count should be 0 for c1
Counter c2(12);// count should be 12 for c2
Counter c3(c2);// count should be 12 for c3?
```

Q9. Arithmetic Assignment operator += that should allow statements lik:

```
c1 += c2
```

Q10. Decrement operator -- that allows statements like

```
c1=c2--
c1=--c2
```

Decrement operator should decrement the value of count by 1?

Q11. Implement the functionalities for Counter class such that the class Interface and Implementation are separate?

Comment: Put the interface into a header file, put the implementation into a cpp file.

Comment: @gnasher729 i believe they meant you should create a pure virtual class, then inherit from it and implement it in another class

Comment: Your question title is misleading. The question's content looks like you want someone to write implementation for you. Regarding interfaces you should get familiar with C++ inheritance model and virtual functions.

Answer (score 0):

This means that you should not define your functions inline, within the class. You should just **declare** the functions in the class and **define** the functions outside of the class.

With that, you can separate the declaration of the class and its implementation. Normally, you would put the class declaration in a header file (.h) and the implementation in a normale C++ source file (.cpp).

in the cpp file you then need to include the header file with an `#include` statement.

Please see an example below:

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// This will be defined in a header file, e.g. "counter.h"

#ifndef COUNTER_H
#define COUNTER_H

#include <iostream>

class Counter {
    int count;
public:
    // Default constructor
    Counter();
    // Dedicated constructorto set a value
    Counter(int c);
    // Copy Constructor
    Counter(const Counter& c);

    // Operator overloading
    Counter& operator += (const Counter& other);

    // Post decrement operator
    Counter operator-- (int);
    // Decrement operator
    Counter operator-- ();
    // Assignment operator
    Counter operator= (const Counter& rhs);

    // Inserter operator
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Counter& c);
};
#endif

// End of header file
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------




// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// The implementation will be implemented in e.g. "counter.cpp"

//#include "counter.h"  // To be uncommented later, if we really have 2 files

// Implementation

// Default constructor
Counter::Counter() : count(0) {};

// Dedicated constructor to set a value
Counter::Counter(int c) : count(c) {};
// Copy Constructor
Counter::Counter(const Counter& c) : count(c.count) {}

// Operator overloading
Counter& Counter::operator += (const Counter& other) { count += other.count; return *this; };

// Post decrement operator
Counter Counter::operator-- (int) { Counter temp; temp.count = count--; return temp; }
// Decrement operator
Counter Counter::operator-- () { Counter temp; temp.count = --count; return temp; }
// Assignment operator
Counter Counter::operator= (const Counter& rhs) { if (this != &rhs) count = rhs.count; return *this; }

// Inserter operator
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Counter& c) { return os << c.count; }

// Test program
int main() {

    Counter c1;
    Counter c2(12);
    Counter c3(c2);

    std::cout << "c1:  " << c1 << "\t\tc2:  " << c2 << "\t\tc3:  " << c3 << '\n';

    c1 += c2;
    std::cout << "c1 += c2:    " << c1 << '\n';

    c1 = c2--;
    std::cout << "c1 = c2--:   " << c1 << '\n';

    c1 = --c2;
    std::cout << "c1 = --c2;:  " << c1 << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

You can copy and paste this into one module. It will compile. If you split this in 2 files, then please uncomment the `#include` statement.